# mysql last url id always comes out to 0

Tags: mysql

```
$urlid = mysql_query("SELECT URL_Id FROM url ORDER BY URL_Id DESC LIMIT 1");

foreach($textnode as $key => $value) {

$value = stripslashes($value);
 $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value, $con);

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO paragraphs (paragraphs, URL_Id)
 VALUES ('$value', '$urlid')");


}
```

has been returning 0 for the URL_Id column. Any suggestions ? It should be returning 1.

Comment: At least fetch the value from result resource for `$urlid `

Comment: Use last_insert_id not a SELECT statement, which is subject to race condition with another insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_query` function retrieving only resource object. then you need to go with looping and retrieve actual data by `mysql_fetch_array()` function.

i.e:

```
while($rowFeach = mysql_fetch_array($urlid));

  print_r($rowFeach);
```

try this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a resource to the query results, **not** the actual selected values.

Please recheck the docs and examples in there.

(Side-note: That select could get expensive depending on the database type, and if your code has any threading, directly or indirectly (e.g. run from a web server with multiple processes), you'll get unexpected duplicate url ids).

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query always returns a resource. Use either [sql_fecth_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) or [mysql_fecth_array](http://www.php.net/manual/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) to get the values in the resource.